# Make non-breakable spaces (~) visible in the PDF and preserve their glue

Tags: symbols, line-breaking, glue

I use several tools to ease my editing process and line and layout optimization. As one of them I’d like to see where I already placed non-breakable spaces `~` directly in the PDF to better understand why certain breakpoints and stretching were chosen.

How could one redefine `~` to show up the in PDF – possibly as a literal tilde symbol ~ – without affecting the line breaking? The substitution should therefore have exactly the same stretch- and shrinkability as the original `~` and, of course, still be non-breaking.

My attempt so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}    
\newcommand\testline{Lorem~ipsum dolor~sit\linebreak}

\begin{document}\noindent\hsize 5cm
\testline
\def~{\textcolor{blue}{\textasciitilde}}
\testline
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of my MWE]

And this or similar is what I’m after:
[image: screenshot of my dreams]

I couldn’t find the default glue of interword spaces and how to place a symbol in the middle of it. If possible `~` should also be redefined in a way to not cause additional errors because it is used in section titles and the bibliography, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions that center the dot between the two words:

```
\def\visiblenobreakspacesymbol{$\cdot$}
\let\invisiblenobreakspace=~
\newdimen\fontdimentwo
\newdimen\fontdimenthree
\newdimen\fontdimenfour
\protected\def\visiblenobreakspace{%
    \fontdimentwo=\fontdimen2\font
    \fontdimenthree=\fontdimen3\font
    \fontdimenfour=\fontdimen4\font
    \fontdimen2\font=\dimexpr\fontdimen2\font/2\relax
    \fontdimen3\font=\dimexpr\fontdimen3\font/2\relax
    \fontdimen4\font=\dimexpr\fontdimen4\font/2\relax
    \invisiblenobreakspace
    \hbox to 0pt{\hss\visiblenobreakspacesymbol\hss}%
    \invisiblenobreakspace
    \fontdimen2\font=\fontdimentwo
    \fontdimen3\font=\fontdimenthree
    \fontdimen4\font=\fontdimenfour}
\def~{\visiblenobreakspace}
```

and

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\visiblenobreakspacesymbol}{$\cdot$}
\let\invisiblenobreakspace=~
\newcounter{nbsp}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\visiblenobreakspace}{%
    \stepcounter{nbsp}%
    \tikzmark{{nbsp-left\arabic{nbsp}}}%
    \invisiblenobreakspace
    \tikzmark{{nbsp-right\arabic{nbsp}}}%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
        \path ({pic cs:nbsp-left\arabic{nbsp}})
            -- ({pic cs:nbsp-right\arabic{nbsp}})
            node [midway,anchor=base] {\visiblenobreakspacesymbol};}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{~}{\visiblenobreakspace}}
```

Both produce the following output:
[image: Fixed-width spaces are replaced with centered dots.]

The first solution should run on any TeX engine with e-TeX available.
The second solution requires two passes, but it is more powerful;
a small change gives the following output:
[image: Fixed-width spaces are replaced with brackets.]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\let\invisiblenobreakspace=~
\newcounter{nbsp}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\visiblenobreakspace}{%
    \stepcounter{nbsp}%
    \tikzmark{{nbsp-left\arabic{nbsp}}}%
    \invisiblenobreakspace
    \tikzmark{{nbsp-right\arabic{nbsp}}}%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw ({pic cs:nbsp-left\arabic{nbsp}}) -- +(0,-0.3ex)
            -| ({pic cs:nbsp-right\arabic{nbsp}});}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{~}{\visiblenobreakspace}}
```

Comment: Works grat as a MWE, but in a real document (a thesis) used exactly the same way, your third code causes many errors: `Missing \endcsname inserted` `Undefined control sequence` `Use of \use@tikzlibrary doesn't match its definition` `Use of \tikz@opt doesn't match its definition` `Use of \tikz@picture doesn't match its definition`. Any idea?

Comment: And your first code solution works with my thesis in the first few pages, but then suddenly all interword spaces are made extremely thin. I declare manual font sizes at various places, maybe this messes with your code.

Comment: I've changed the versions with tikzmark so they should hopefully work now. I couldn't reproduce the error with the first version (how exactly do you change the font size?). Does it help to protect that version too: `\def\newtilde{...}` instead of `\def~{...}` and then `\def~{\protect\newtilde}`?

Comment: The `\tikzmark`-solutions work now, thanks! The first one got broken because I placed a custom macro instead of `$\cdot$` inside (for more involved formatting) and didn't `\protect` it there. Doing that it works as well and I prefer not having to compile twice.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}    
\newcommand\testlinei{Lorem~ipsum dolor~sit\linebreak}
\newcommand\testlineii{Lorem~ipsum dolor~sit~skdjfh~skdhf~skfdh~sdf\linebreak}

\begin{document}\noindent\hsize 5cm
\testlinei
\testlineii
\let\oldtilde=~
\def~{\rlap{\textcolor{blue}{$\cdot$}}\oldtilde}
\testlinei
\testlineii
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\cdot` really seems to be better suited than the wider tilde symbol. Thanks for introducing me to `\rlap`!

Answer (score 4):

You can use leaders:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\testline{Lorem~ipsum dolor~sit\linebreak no underfull}

\renewcommand~{\visiblenobreakspace{}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\visiblenobreakspace{%
  \leavevmode\nobreak
  \cleaders\hbox to 0.3em{\hss\textcolor{blue}{\v{}}\hss}\hskip
  \ifdim\spaceskip>0pt
    \spaceskip
  \else
    \fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hsize 5cm
\testline

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a rule, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\testline{Lorem~ipsum dolor~sit\linebreak no underfull}

\renewcommand~{\visiblenobreakspace{}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\visiblenobreakspace{%
  \leavevmode\nobreak
  {\color{blue}%
   \cleaders\hrule height 1ex depth -0.7ex\hskip
   \ifdim\spaceskip>0pt
     \spaceskip
   \else
     \fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font
   \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hsize 5cm
\testline

\end{document}
```

[image]